# 'C# script task to remove quadruple quotes before loading .CSV file"

Tags: c#, ssis, etl, flat-file, script-task

I have a fairly basic SSIS package that will load a .csv file into a SQL table. However, when the package is attempting to read the .csv source in the data flow task I receive the error message: "The column delimiter for column 'X' was not found.  An error occurred while processing file "file.csv" on data row 'Y'."

In this case, what is happening is there are a few rows out of thousands that contain a string within quadruple quotes, i.e. "Jane "Jill" Doe." Manually removing the quotes from these rows in UltraEdit works, however, I am attempting to automate these packages. A derived column did not work as it is an issue with the delimiter.

Turns out I need a script task to remove the quadruple quotes before the package can load the file properly. The code below (which I pieced together from various sources) is accepted by SSIS as errorless but encounters a DTS Script Task Runtime Error upon execution:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#endregion

namespace ST_a881d570d1a6495e84824a72bd28f44f
 {
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\File.csv");

        fileContents = fileContents.Replace("<body>", "<body onload='jsFx();' />");
        fileContents = fileContents.Replace("</body>", "</body>");

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\File.csv", fileContents);

    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

    }
}
```

The alternative script I have is:

```
{
string filepath = (string)Dts.Variables[@C:\\"File.csv"].Value;
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
fileContents = fileContents.Replace("\"\"", "");

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@C:\\"File.csv", fileContents);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CSV files *can* contain double quotes in fields as long as they are escaped. The SSIS Flat File source doesn't support this though. SQL Server 2017 added full CSV support for [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#input-file-format-options). You could use it instead of modifying the source file

Comment: It should. It doesn't matter which client executes the command. The path should be accessible though, ie it should be a path on the server itself or a network share visible to the SQL Server service account

Comment: I apparently do not have the permission level to run BULK INSERTS. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following C# example will search a csv file, remove any double quotes that are contained with double quoted text, and then write the modified contents back out to the file.  The regex returns a match on any double quote that either is not at the beginning or end of the string, or doesn't have a comma directly before/after it and replaces the double quote with an empty string.  You're probably already doing this, but make sure the variable holding the file path is listed in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field of the Script Task.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


string filePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();

List<String> outputRecords = new List<String>();
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
 using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(filePath))
 {
  string line;
  while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
      if (line.Contains(","))
      {
          string[] split = line.Split(',');

       //replace double qoutes between text
       line = Regex.Replace(line, "(?<!(,|^))\"(?!($|,))", x => x.Value.Replace("\"", ""));

      }
      outputRecords.Add(line);
    }
 }

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
 {
     //write filtered records back to file
     foreach (string s in outputRecords)
         sw.WriteLine(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: When i saw the question is related to c# i was waiting to see you answering :)

Comment: Thanks @Hadi :), after running into enough odd scenarios over time I've been accustomed to looking to C# for things like this.